# Adjust a detected 2D map to a reference 2D map

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, 2d

I have a map with some reference positions that correspond to the center (small cross) of some objects like this:
[image: reference positions]

I take pictures to find my objects but in the pictures I have some noise so I can't always find all of the objects, it can be something like this:
[image: detected positions]

From the few found positions I need to know where in the picture the other not found objects should be. I've being reading about this for the last couple of days and experimenting but I can't find a proper way of doing this. In some examples they start by calculating the center of masses and translating them together, then rotating, some other examples use least squares minimization and start by a rotation. I can't use OpenCV or any other APIs, just plain C++. I can use Eigen library if that helps. Can anyone give me some pointers on this?

EDIT:
I've solved the correspondence between points, the picture is never very different from the reference so for each found position I can search for its corresponding reference. In brief, I have one 2D matrix with reference points and another 2D matrix with found points. In the found matrix of points, the not found points are saved as NaN just to keep the same matrix size, the NaN points are not used in the calculations.

Comment: So you have the reference image top which guarantees that the position of the objects are in exact that relation to each other in the query image?

Comment: @Timo yes, I have the reference positions in a perfect image

Comment: I'm investigating the "Affine transform" but its lots of math and I'm kinda overloading right now...

Comment: @Timo I have the reference positions and after processing the new image I have a few found positions, my objective is to know where the missing objects center might be. Apparently this can be done using an Affine Transformation. I'm using 2D positions.

Comment: An affine transformation is a transformation between two spaces that keep their correlations (in your case: the distances and rotations between the points). Finding this transformation is the problem. Since your 2nd point set (the noisy image) isn't complete you cannot compare intrinsics like center of mass to each other. You have to match your detected points against your reference points to find the transformation. Search for *Iterative Closest Point* algorithm and maybe look at an implementation.

Comment: @Timo I already solved that step because points are far away from each other so for each detected point I already know which is the corresponding reference point. I just search around each detected point and make sure I have one and only one reference point. The taken picture is never really very different from the reference but I need pixel precision for the estimated positions

Comment: Just found this for 3D: https://github.com/oleg-alexandrov/projects/blob/master/eigen/Kabsch.cpp going to try to make it 2D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work with the code from here:
https://github.com/oleg-alexandrov/projects/blob/master/eigen/Kabsch.cpp

I'm calling the **Find3DAffineTransform** function and passing it my 2D maps, as this function expects 3D maps I've made all z coordinates = 0 and it works. If I have some time I'll try to adapt it to 2D.
Meanwhile a fellow programmer (Regis :-) found also this, that should work:
https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__Geometry__Module.html#gab3f5a82a24490b936f8694cf8fef8e60
Its the function umeyama() that returns the transformation between two point sets. Its part of Eigen library. Didn't have the time to test this.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already matched the points to one another, finding the transform is straight forward:

```
Eigen::Affine2d findAffine(Eigen::Matrix2Xd const& refCloud, Eigen::Matrix2Xd const& targetCloud)
{
    // get translation
    auto refCom = centerOfMass(refCloud);
    auto refAtOrigin = refCloud.colwise() - refCom;

    auto targetCom = centerOfMass(targetCloud);
    auto targetAtOrigin = targetCloud.colwise() - targetCom;

    // get scale
    auto scale = targetAtOrigin.rowwise().norm().sum() / refAtOrigin.rowwise().norm().sum();

    // get rotation
    auto covMat = refAtOrigin * targetAtOrigin.transpose();
    auto svd = covMat.jacobiSvd(Eigen::ComputeFullU | Eigen::ComputeFullV);
    auto rot = svd.matrixV() * svd.matrixU().transpose();   

    // combine the transformations
    Eigen::Affine2d trans = Eigen::Affine2d::Identity();
    trans.translate(targetCom).scale(scale).rotate(rot).translate(-refCom);
    return trans;
}
```

`refCloud` is your reference point set and `targetCloud` is the set of points you have found in your image. It is important that the clouds match index wise, so `refCloud[n]` must be the corresponding point to `targetCloud[n]`. This means that you have to remove all NaNs from your matrix and cherry pick the correspondances in your reference point set.

Here is a full example. I'm using OpenCV to draw the stuff:

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using Point = Eigen::Vector2d;

template <typename TMatrix>
Point centerOfMass(TMatrix const& points)
{
    return points.rowwise().sum() / points.cols();
}

Eigen::Affine2d findAffine(Eigen::Matrix2Xd const& refCloud, Eigen::Matrix2Xd const& targetCloud)
{
    // get translation
    auto refCom = centerOfMass(refCloud);
    auto refAtOrigin = refCloud.colwise() - refCom;

    auto targetCom = centerOfMass(targetCloud);
    auto targetAtOrigin = targetCloud.colwise() - targetCom;

    // get scale
    auto scale = targetAtOrigin.rowwise().norm().sum() / refAtOrigin.rowwise().norm().sum();

    // get rotation
    auto covMat = refAtOrigin * targetAtOrigin.transpose();
    auto svd = covMat.jacobiSvd(Eigen::ComputeFullU | Eigen::ComputeFullV);
    auto rot = svd.matrixV() * svd.matrixU().transpose();   

    // combine the transformations
    Eigen::Affine2d trans = Eigen::Affine2d::Identity();
    trans.translate(targetCom).scale(scale).rotate(rot).translate(-refCom);
    return trans;
}

void drawCloud(cv::Mat& img, Eigen::Matrix2Xd const& cloud, Point const& origin, Point const& scale, cv::Scalar const& color, int thickness = cv::FILLED)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < cloud.cols(); c++)
    {
        auto p = origin + cloud.col(c).cwiseProduct(scale);
        cv::circle(img, {int(p.x()), int(p.y())}, 5, color, thickness, cv::LINE_AA);
    }
}

int main()
{
    // generate sample reference
    std::vector<Point> points = {{4, 9}, {4, 4}, {6, 9}, {6, 4}, {8, 9}, {8, 4}, {10, 9}, {10, 4}, {12, 9}, {12, 4}};
    Eigen::Matrix2Xd fullRefCloud(2, points.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < points.size(); i++)
        fullRefCloud.col(i) = points[i];

    // generate sample target
    Eigen::Matrix2Xd refCloud = fullRefCloud.leftCols(fullRefCloud.cols() * 0.6);
    Eigen::Affine2d refTransformation = Eigen::Affine2d::Identity();
    refTransformation.translate(Point(8, -4)).rotate(4.3).translate(-centerOfMass(refCloud)).scale(1.5);
    Eigen::Matrix2Xd targetCloud = refTransformation * refCloud;

    // find the transformation
    auto transform = findAffine(refCloud, targetCloud);
    std::cout << "Original: \n" << refTransformation.matrix() << "\n\nComputed: \n" << transform.matrix() << "\n";

    // apply the computed transformation
    Eigen::Matrix2Xd queryCloud = fullRefCloud.rightCols(fullRefCloud.cols() - refCloud.cols());
    queryCloud = transform * queryCloud;

    // draw it
    Point scale = {15, 15}, origin = {100, 300};
    cv::Mat img(600, 600, CV_8UC3);
    cv::line(img, {0, int(origin.y())}, {800, int(origin.y())}, {});
    cv::line(img, {int(origin.x()), 0}, {int(origin.x()), 800}, {});    
    drawCloud(img, refCloud, origin, scale, {0, 255, 0});
    drawCloud(img, fullRefCloud, origin, scale, {255, 0, 0}, 1);
    drawCloud(img, targetCloud, origin, scale, {0, 0, 255});
    drawCloud(img, queryCloud, origin, scale, {255, 0, 255}, 1);

    cv::flip(img, img, 0);
    cv::imshow("img", img);
    cv::waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: We posted a solution almost at the same time :-)  Your code is very similar to the other solution I found, thank you very much for your help!